# WPF: ComboBox displays "(namespace).(classname)" instead of data

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I want to get my `ComboBox` in XAML to bind to my `List` collection of custom objects in code behind.

Currently the `ComboBox` lists for each entry `dpwpf.Contact` which is my `{namespace}.{classname}`.

What do I need to put in the XAML to tell it to list out, e.g. LastName + FirstName?

I know it's something like `{Binding Path=... Value=...}` but I can't get it.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="dpwpf.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Select the contact:"/>
            <ComboBox Name="theContactList"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
namespace dpwpf
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            StoreDB db = new StoreDB();
            List<Contact> contacts = db.GetContacts()
            theContactList.ItemsSource = contacts.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

## Answer:

```
<Window x:Class="dpwpf.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:dpwpf">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Contact}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                <TextBlock Text=" "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Margin="10">
            <TextBlock Text="Contact Name:" Foreground="#555"/>
            <TextBox Name="theName"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Select the contact:"/>
            <ComboBox Name="theContactList"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF IsEditable=true ComboBox filled with objects displays the ToString() as the selected item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844156/wpf-iseditable-true-combobox-filled-with-objects-displays-the-tostring-as-the)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can override the `ToString` method of `Contact`, or you can define a `DataTemplate` in WPF.

```
xmlns:dpwpf="... namespace of dpwpf"

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dpwpf:Contact}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}">
            <TextBlock Text=" ">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}">
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

This allows you to define how a `Contact` object will appear anywhere in the window. If you want to limit this to the `ComboBox` you can add the `DataTemplate` just to the `ComboBox` resources.

Comment: wow, I'm going to have to let that sink in, you have a StackPanel going on inside a ComboBoxItem. So the posted answer code works above but I don't see the connection between the my ComboBox and the DataTemplate, I'm expecting the DataTemplate to have a name and the ComboBox refer to it.

Comment: The combobox shows Contact objects. So WPF searches the visual tree for a DataTemplate that displays Contacts, and uses that template. If there's no template then it defaults to using ToString. There is no direct connection except through the Contact object.

Comment: This is the beauty of WPF. You define a way of showing a data object, and then wherever that object turns up the template is used to display it.

Comment: Also, the stackpanel was just there to get the "firstname" + "lastname" look. You could do the same thing with a Binding converter, but doing it this way is easier.

Comment: Autocompletion won't work when working around the issue like this. Take a look at Rafa's answer.

Answer (score 7):

Just add this in you ComboBox tag (xaml code)

```
TextSearch.TextPath ="Title"
```

`ToString()` modification affects all future cases you need it, I don't recommend you to do that.

See that example:
http://simplesample.site90.com/wpf_combobox.php

Comment: I knew that it's some property like `TextSearch.TextPath`, but boy is it hard to find the right answer among those suggesting `ToString`s and `DisplayMemberPath`s... Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

What the binding mechanism is doing is calling ToString() on the type that is being bound.  Because I guess you're not overriding ToString() it'll just so the namespace.type instead of something useful.

As rebelious says, you can use DisplayMember to tell the binding to use a property of that name for the display value or you can override ToString() as below to get your custom property to show.

```
public void Contact
{
 public string FirstName { get; set; }
 public override string ToString()
 {
   return FirstName; 
 }
}
```

Comment: this is nice, but I might have other controls which want to override differently, and as far as I understand I only get one override.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use DisplayMember="TheValue"

you can add this in the XAML or in the CLR
also note your binding in cose and not through the XAML.
i think this relates to a prvious question of yours.
which implements the binding through ObjectDataProvider
use that example and add the DisplayMemeber="memeber" in the XAML

HTH,
Eric,

Comment: yes, this will work, but I want to be able to format the text instead the combobox item, e.g. lastname + " " + firstname

Comment: Hi Edward, sorry it took me so long.
you have a couple of ways to tackle the problem.
1) add a property FullName which returns this.lastname + ", " + this.firstname. and use it as the deisplay member.


HH,
Eric

Comment: 2) use a IValueConverter to convert the displaed vaule, you can use as a static resource in the XAML and add the Converter XML propert.