# WPF IsEditable=true ComboBox filled with objects displays the ToString() as the selected item

Tags: wpf, combobox, editing, tostring

The Wpf combo box allows editing, and this is fine if all your combo box items are strings, or have a ToString() method defined on them.

When you select an item, it is displayed as Text, it does not use a DataTemplate, it just calls ToString() on the item that is selected.

I get a list of items in my combo drop down that are formatted using my item template, when i select one i get the name of the object i.e. **MyNamespace.MyObjectName**

Some solutions have been

- use ValuePath to bind to a property
  on the object, but if you require
  your display to be more than one of
  these, bad luck.
- implement the ToString() method on
  your object

is there another way around?

Comment: yes the second method works perfectly.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can do this entirely within Xaml

```
<ComboBox IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsEditable="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjectCollection}"
        TextSearch.TextPath="MyObjectName">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyObjectName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

The upside is that you can define and change this however you want in your XAML without any code-behind.  You bind the ItemsSource to your collection of objects, and then you set the path on which to base your search to [TextSearch.TextPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textsearch.textpath).  Then, within you custom ItemTemplate you can bind the TextBlock to something else outside of the object's ToString method.

Comment: Forgot to add, the key here is to keep your DataTemplate.  The TextSearch.TextPath attached property is what makes your textbox within the ComboBox show whatever property you want.

Comment: absolute gold. the attached properties get me every time, because its so easy to stay unaware of them. Thanks.

Comment: *OMG* I wish I could upvote this more than once.  I also wish it had come up when I searched for "WPF ComboBox SelectedValuePath ToString" -- hopefully mentioning them in a comment will help some other poor sap not chase his tail for 2 hours trying to figure this out in the future.

Half the battle in using a large framework is learning how to think like the people that designed the framework (assuming you can't just memorize the entire huge framework. ;-))  I was definitely thinking at this one in the "wrong" direction.

Comment: What if you are using multiple bound properties inside that datatemplate. I tried it on mine and now when you select something from the drop down it only displays the path i set to TextSearch.TextPath. The items in the drop down display properly but the selected item display does just the the TextPath i used.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(VS.95).aspx) to convert the "object" to a string value and back.  See the example code in the IValueConverter link for details.

Comment: thanks for the answer, man i feel like an idiot, i knew this. ill blame it on friday. :)

Comment: ive used converters many times, where would you put this converter, not on the ItemsSource property, Ive tried on the SelectedItem property and the converter gets hit, but when i return a string i still get the MyNamespace.MyObjectName, have you tried this with a combobox before?

Comment: Check out the example in the link.  It shows you how to use a converter with a combobox (via the comboboxes ItemsTemplate).