# Combobox displays namespace.ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a combobox which binds to `ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel>`

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllCustomers}" IsEditable="True"/>
```

If I use DisplayMemberPath property, the dropdown and the selecteditem displays correctly

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllCustomers}" DisplayMemberPath="CustomerName" IsEditable="True"/>
```

[image]

But if a DataTemplate is assigned, the selecteditem is not displayed properly

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllCustomers}" SelectedValue="CustomerName" IsEditable="True">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CustomerName}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ComboBox>
```

[image]

**Edit:
I found the issue, but not the solution, and the issue is if the ComboBox has IsEditable="True" it creates the problem.**

---

**Code abstract:**

```
public class AllCustomersViewModel
{
   public ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel> AllCustomers {get; set;}
}

public class CustomerViewModel
{
   public string CustomerName;
   public short CustomerID;
}
```

Which property is to be set (or how) to display the selectedvalue/item correctly.

Thank you very much in advance.

---

---

**ActualCode**

```
public class AccountTransactionsViewModel
{
    DataRepository _repository;

    public AccountTransactionsViewModel()
    {
        _repository = new DataRepository();
        CreateAccountsViewModel();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<AccountViewModel> AllAccounts { get; set; }

    void CreateAccountsViewModel()
    {
        List<AccountViewModel> allAccounts = _repository.GetAccounts()
                                                        .Select(a => new AccountViewModel(a, _repository))
                                                        .ToList();

        AllAccounts =  new ObservableCollection<AccountViewModel>(allAccounts);            
    }
}



  public class AccountViewModel
  {
       Account _account;
       DataRepository _repository;

       public AccountViewModel(Account account, DataRepository repository)
       {
            _account = account;
            _repository = repository;
       }

       public short AccountID { get { return _account.AccountID; } set { } }
       public string AccountName { get { return _account.AccountName; } set { } }        
  }
```

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox Name="customerCombobox" ItemsSource="{Binding AllAccounts}" IsEditable="True">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding AccountName}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>                     
                    </ComboBox>
```

**Edit:**

**I found the issue, but not the solution, and the issue is if the ComboBox has IsEditable="True" it creates the problem.**

Comment: Something is messed up in your sample: you have `AccountName` in code and `CustomerName` in XAML. Can you post your actual code? Because setting the `ItemTemplate` should effect the also the selected item as well and your code should work.

Comment: @nemesv: Oh yes sorry.. I corrected it. THis happend coz i manually typed the dataclasses here.

Comment: check for binding errors in the output in VS, they'll give a hint on the reason why this fails. Also I am not sure setting SelectedValue like that works.

Comment: @stijn There are absolutely no BindingExpression errors in output. :(

Comment: Please see the last two lines in edit

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF IsEditable=true ComboBox filled with objects displays the ToString() as the selected item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844156/wpf-iseditable-true-combobox-filled-with-objects-displays-the-tostring-as-the)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF IsEditable=true ComboBox filled with objects displays the ToString() as the selected item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844156/wpf-iseditable-true-combobox-filled-with-objects-displays-the-tostring-as-the)

Answer (score 3):

The full name of the object's type is displayed when there's no template available. Also the full type name is the result of the `ToString()` method call. So either override `ToString()` method or investigate more about the data templates.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllCustomers}" SelectedValue="CustomerName">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item.CustomerName}"/>
             </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: No Items are displayed in drop-down(as expected). Actually the problem isn't the datatemplate, but SelectedItemTemplate is somehow acting weird

Answer (score 0):

If want to show the selected values some property you should use the `SelectedValuePath`.
`SelectedValue` will hold the value of the `SelectedItems` property you want to show.

Without setting the `SelectedValuePath` the framework tries to get back whole `SelectedItem` - in this case `AccountViewModel` instance - converted to string

```
<ComboBox Name="customerCombobox" ItemsSource="{Binding AllAccounts}" SelectedValuePath="AccountName">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding AccountName}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>                     
                </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because I wanted to display a custom text in the combobox items.
When you have an `ItemTemplate` you cannot set the `DisplayMemberPath` of the ComboBox displays the class name when you don't have the `toString()` function implemented.

You just have to use `TextSearch.TextPath` and your problem is solved.

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" TextSearch.TextPath="MySelectedTextField">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock ToolTip="{Binding MyTooltipField}">
                <Run Text="{Binding MyCustomField1}" />
                <Run Text=" - "/>
                <Run Text="{Binding MyCustomField2}" />
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```